# Inserting Date Time by pressing F5 like in notepad

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I made this whatever.py file in Preferences - Browse Packages - User (folder)

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, time
class InsertDatetimeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
def run(self, edit):
    sel = self.view.sel();
    for s in sel:
        self.view.replace(edit, s, time.strftime( '%H:%M %d/%m/%Y' ))
```

then

in preferences - keybindings - User, added this line:

```
{ "keys": ["f5"], "command": "insert_datetime"}
```

and this works as expected by pressing F5, I can insert datetime but when I do this this datetime is selected and when I press enter to go to a newline, it is deleted. Do you know which part should I change in the above code to NOT select all datetime string after pressing F5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `view.insert` to add string at the second end of selection:

```
class InsertDatetimeCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        sel = self.view.sel()
        for s in sel:
            self.view.insert(edit, s.b, time.strftime( '%H:%M %d/%m/%Y' ))
```

The problem with `replace` is that you are replacing regions with a `Selection`. So after running the command, time string is selected so it will be replaced when you hit `Enter`. You can do something like `sel.clear()` or modify each region to fix it.

**Update:**
As OdatNurd said, using `s.a` will be confused in that case. Using `s.b` would be more consistent.

Comment: Tried this but did not work. Not even printing date time. Did you try the change you mentioned?  Can you paste the whole code?

Comment: I've updated the whole code. It works on my side, if it doesn't work can you give the output in the console?

Comment: This answer works for me as well, I would check the console for errors. Note also that you can also easily do this with a `run` method containing only this code: `self.view.run_command("insert", {"characters": time.strftime('%H:%M %d/%m/%Y')})`

Comment: As a side note, the `a` attribute gives you the first end of the selection, not the start of the selection, so if you select text first and select right to left, the insertion may not happen where you want. This also won't clobber the selected text with the inserted text (which may or may not be a big deal).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that difference and have updated the answer.

Comment: thank you so much. I forgot to add "import sublime, sublime_plugin, time" part. I added that and that worked like a charm. Thank you...